# Qt 5.2 QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a noob - not good with QML or C++ yet, but getting there. I seem to have hit a stumbling block I can't get past. I'm receiving the following error in my attempt to run a build and I'm not sure what I missed in my code...

**QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::buttonClicked_enable() to TLA_Funcs::sys_enable()
**

I've looked through the other versions of the question here and it seems that I have my code correct, but I still get the error. Can someone take a peek? Here's the relevant sample of my code (the rest is too long and I left out the guts of the function - too long).

QML Code:

```
Rectangle {
id: main
width: 800
height: 600
color: "#abcfe9"
border.width: 4
border.color: "#000000"

signal buttonClicked_enable()

Button {
    id: enable
    x: 628
    y: 55
    text: "ENABLE"
    onClicked:buttonClicked_enable()
    }
//....
}
```

My class header:
    #ifndef TLA_FUNCS_H
    #define TLA_FUNCS_H

```
#include <QObject>

class TLA_Funcs : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TLA_Funcs(QObject *parent = 0);
signals:

public slots:
    Q_INVOKABLE void sys_enable(){return ;}  
private:
};    
#endif
```

And in my main.cpp file:

```
#include "TLA_Funcs.h"

TLA_Funcs::TLA_Funcs(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}


int main (int argc, char*argv[]) {

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView(QUrl("main.qml")); 
    view->show();

    QQuickItem *item = view->rootObject();  
    TLA_Funcs *funcs = new TLA_Funcs(); 


    QObject::connect(item, SIGNAL(buttonClicked_enable()), funcs, SLOT(sys_enable()));

}
```

I've defined the signals in the parent rectangle, and in the button code I've tried using:

```
onClicked:main.buttonClicked_enable()
```

as well as:

```
onClicked: {
            buttonClicked_enable()
            TLA_Funcs.sys_enable()
}
```

That didn't help either. I also tried defining the functions under "signal" in the class, but that made more of a mess. Can someone at least point me in the right direction, and keep in mind, I'm still a noob...  Thanks All!!!

Comment: Do you run this via qt creator?

Comment: Yes, I was using Qt Creator. I used it to create the C++ class as well. This compiles, I just get the error when I hit "Run"

Comment: Copy the main.qml where the application gets it final exe compiled and linked. Does the error come after that too?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for... rephrase it? This is how the error shows up if that's what you're asking:

Starting X:\project1\TLA_UDP\Test_GUI.exe...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::buttonClicked_enable() to TLA_Funcs::sys_enable()

Comment: The problem is you're trying to connect a `null` object, so your call to `view->rootObject` has gone wrong. Looking at your code the one that jumps out is you're doing `QQuickView *view = new...`, the docs usually show it as `QQuickView view` instead. Try switching it out and see if it helps.

Comment: I did see that before and when I changed it, I got  "conversion from QQuickView* to non scalar type "QQuickView" requested" as well as complaining about the reference being a pointer type.

Comment: So I just made a dummy project, set up the exact same way (my project has 25 buttons and checkboxes) with one button. IT built and ran. When I clicked the button, the debugger gave me a reference error becaus ethe function is undefined, which I assume means that just having "return" as a function is insufficient. I'm ok with that. Just not sure why it rejects my code for my project...

Answer (score -2):

Problem Solved: there was an error in the .pro file. I copied the code into a new project and it worked correctly 100%. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: what was the error on the pro file? Maybe you could share.. I would vote up if I found that your solution was applicable to me...

Comment: Thanks @LeonardoAlvesMachado for the offer, but I'm not here for upvotes... that's what Imgur is for. This was completed over 2 years ago, the project is long since over for me and I don't remember what I did other than to copy the code into a new project.... sorry. Wish I could be of further help.